# How can I configure Windows Server 2008 R2 to NAT while connecting to the internet with PPPoE?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, nat, pppoe

The only avalable way to connect to the internet with a static IP address for our server is using PPPoE.
Now, I want to know if we could config the NAT on a PPPoE connection.

We have two NIC. More over I know how to NAT when we have an static IP address on a NIC (I know the regular way).

Comment: if you know the regular way, then the solution is there. Try getting to the NIC properties from which you are getting internet. Then go to the sharing tab, enable sharing, and select the NIC on which you want to enable this internet. This will keep the first NIC same as before but change the 2nd NIC with the ip 192.168.1.1 (or 192.168.0.1 note: i dont remember the exact ip at the moment but it will be one of the two).
the clients connecting through 2nd NIC will get the same ip as of the respective NIC

Comment: @booota: There isn't any sharing tab in the properties. More over I said that we can connect to the internet through a PPPoE connection. PPPoE connection has not any sharing option too.

Comment: Network address translation (NAT) allows you to share a connection to the public Internet through a single interface with a single public IP address. The computers on the private network use private, non-routable addresses. NAT maps the private addresses to the public address.

About how to enable and configure NAT in windows server 2008, please refer to the article below:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd469812.aspx

view full thread @ http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsserver2008r2networking/thread/3abfb22b-9e54-47b4-827d-5f705f7d68c7