# Windows server 2012 PPPoE share to NAT

Tags: windows-server-2012, nat, share, pppoe

I have dedicated server (Windows Server 2012) and two network ports on NIC, my ISP gives internet connection via PPPoE. One network port is using for ISP cable, and second one for Windows 8.1 local PC.
I can share internet connection only if ISP cable goes thought router (in that case I have two lan connection on window server, and there's no problem to configure NAT with RRAS service).

Can I share windows server PPPoE connection to my local PC (like NAT) without using router?

Question similar to [How can I configure Windows Server 2008 R2 to NAT while connecting to the internet with PPPoE?](https://serverfault.com/questions/272608/how-can-i-configure-windows-server-2008-r2-to-nat-while-connecting-to-the-intern), but unanswered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I solve problem why ICS is not working after sharing PPPoE adapter, all I need to do is to restart the ICS (SharedAccess) after connecting to PPPoE, then NAT is working perfectly.

Very weird ...